# ClassNotFoundException: org.dom4j.DocumentException

Tags: java, eclipse, classnotfoundexception, dom4j

I am trying to debug (F11 on Eclipse) a java GUI application I inherited but while the application runs fine (minus a tiny fix I need to apply) outside of the Eclipse IDE, it produces the following exception when launched from Eclipse (either F11 or Ctrl+F11):

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/dom4j/DocumentException
    at com.example.myapp.LoginWindow.buildHibernateConfig(LoginWindow.java:178)
    at com.example.myapp.LoginWindow.actionPerformed(LoginWindow.java:141)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:357)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicRootPaneUI$Actions.actionPerformed(BasicRootPaneUI.java:191)
    at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.notifyAction(SwingUtilities.java:1639)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBinding(JComponent.java:2859)
    at javax.swing.KeyboardManager.fireBinding(KeyboardManager.java:267)
    at javax.swing.KeyboardManager.fireKeyboardAction(KeyboardManager.java:216)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBindingsForAllComponents(JComponent.java:2936)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBindings(JComponent.java:2928)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(JComponent.java:2822)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6074)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2039)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4660)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2097)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4488)
    at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1856)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:722)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1000)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:865)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:686)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4532)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2097)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2489)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4488)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:668)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:81)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:627)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:625)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:641)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:639)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:638)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.dom4j.DocumentException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 47 more
```

My initial search on this found that [the dom4j library may be missing](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-error-initial-sessionfactory-creation-failed-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-orgdom4jdocumentexception/) but adding it to the pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.saxon</groupId>
        <artifactId>saxon</artifactId>
        <version>9.1.0.8</version>
    </dependency>        
   <dependency>
        <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Did **not** solve the problem.

Any idea why I am getting this exception (**only when launching from Eclipse**) and how to solve this problem?

BTW, the `saxson` dependency was added only because trying to use [the latest dom4j](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cdom4j%7Cdom4j%7C20040902.021138%7Cjar) resulted in unresolved dependencies when building. But since I downgraded to `dom4j 1.6.1` I could eliminate the saxon dependency so the pom.xml file only contains now:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: Is it a Maven m2e project or a simple java project in eclipse?

Comment: @anoopelias Yes, it *is* a Maven m2e project. It has **no** problems downloading the dependency and building with it. Weird.

Comment: If you have several other dependencies you can try to change the export order in eclipse. Move dom4j up the list so that you don't have another dependency that includes an older version of Dom4j.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go to the Eclipse "debug" view and get the actual command that Eclipse is using to run your program. 
You should suspend the program as soon as it starts, then right click on the SECOND line in the "debug" view, then choose properties.
You will see a window called "process properties" from which can copy the command generated  by Eclipse to run your program. 
You can paste the command into a terminal and then see how Java resolves the classpath. See which jars are actually loaded by adding the -verbose parameter.

EDIT - Just to make it clear, when I say "debug view" I mean

```
"Main Menu"->"Window"->"Show View"->"Debug"
```

Answer (score 2):

Bro,you need to import all jar files to run your program.These are mandatory for running your project

Poi-3.10-Final.jar

Poi-ooxml-3.10-Final.jar

Poi-ooxml-schemas-3.10.jar

Xmlbeans-2.30.jar